# Limit route groups HTTP methods in Echo

Tags: go, routes, echo, go-echo

I'm using groups in Echo to pack some routes with a common prefix but when I get the list of routes, it returns routes for all HTTP methods.

##### main.go

```
e := echo.New()
adminGroup := e.Group("/admin")
adminGroup.GET("/", adminIndex)
```

I use this to get list of routes:

```
e.Routes()
```

##### Output

```
...
   {
      "method": "TRACE",
      "path": "/admin/*",
      "name": "github.com/labstack/echo/v4.glob..func1"
   },
   {
      "method": "PATCH",
      "path": "/admin",
      "name": "github.com/labstack/echo/v4.glob..func1"
   },
   {
      "method": "PROPFIND",
      "path": "/admin",
      "name": "github.com/labstack/echo/v4.glob..func1"
   },
   {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/admin/*",
      "name": "github.com/labstack/echo/v4.glob..func1"
   }
...
```

I expect to get route just to `GET admin/`